# Notification Service Extension errors in iOS 12.1 with AVFoundation

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Our app use notification service extension to play custom audio. It works fine before iOS12.0(include 12.0).
But when i upgrade to 12.1, and found it can't play custom audio in background.

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far and possible error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Most extensions are not allowed to activate an audio session, and so cannot play audio or use speech synthesis. This wasn't being enforced consistently prior to iOS 12.1, but now it is.

Some extensions (such as notification content extensions) present UI to the user, and those are allowed to activate an audio session.

Background modes in info.plist are not allowed for app extensions (and will get your app rejected by App Review)

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others